# How to download multiple images using Glide [Android]?

Tags: java, android, image, android-image, android-glide

Provided I have an array of image URLs, I am trying to download all these images **one-by-one** using glide. Presently, I am able to download a single image when I provide its URL. And here is the code:

```
 private void downx()
{
    File sd = getExternalCacheDir();
    File folder = new File(sd, "/mobio/");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        if (!folder.mkdir()) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Cannot create a directory!");
        } else {
            folder.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    final File[] fileName = {new File(folder, "one.jpg"), new File(folder, "two.jpg"),new File(folder, "three.jpg")};


    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                        theBitmap = Glide.
                        with(getApplicationContext()).
                        load(urls[2]).
                        asBitmap().
                        into(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL,Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL).
                        get();
            }
            catch (final ExecutionException e)
            {
                Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException e)
            {
                Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void dummy) {
            if (null != theBitmap) {
                // The full bitmap should be available here
                Log.d("TAG", "Image loaded");
                Log.e("GLIDE","I am Ready");
                try {
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(fileName[1]));
                    theBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                    outputStream.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.execute();



}
```

Now the **problem** is: What approach do I adopt if I need to download multiple images, and how do I force my code to adapt to handle multiple downloads?

Answer (score 1):

I have used a class which takes a list of URLs and downloads the Images to a file. Please check this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/bpr10/a765a015bf1c774816ba58c7ae6413d6) for more. This uses Picasso to download Images but you can edit the download code to use glide as well. Should be a one line change. Hope this helps.

https://gist.github.com/bpr10/a765a015bf1c774816ba58c7ae6413d6

Answer (score -2):

I guess it will be better to use Download Manager as it will handle queuing, network availability etc.